# How to give different gradient in horizontal bar chart in Pentaho report designer

Tags: jfreechart, pentaho, beanshell, pentaho-design-studio

Is there any way to give different gradient color in each bar of bar chart in pentaho report designer. I'm trying with BeanShall Script but unable to get the gradient top to bottom, also I'm getting same gradient color in all the other bars too.

I'm attaching a image which is my desire result.

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Regards,
Ankit Patni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the solution on my own. Written a blog for the same
http://bineedsui.wordpress.com/2013/12/19/horizontal-gradient-bar-chart-in-pentaho-reporting-designer/